# Use class instance names as legend entry for e.g. a plot

Tags: python

Say that I have defined a class and I make a couple of instances of it:

```
A = MyClass()
B = MyClass()
```

Assume now that I defined a `my_plot` function that takes instances of classes `MyClass` as input, e.g. I have something like the following:

```
def my_plot(X,Y):
    # Do something and plot
    plt.legend([?,??])
```

that I can call with `my_plot(A,B)`.

I wish to replace the `?` and the `??` in the line `plt.legend([?,??])` of the pseudo-code snippet above with with `A` and `B`, respectively.
So far, a way to circumnavigate the problem is to equip the `MyClass` with an attribute `name` and do something like this

```
A = MyClass('nameA')
B = MyClass('nameB')
```

and then

```
def my_plot(X,Y):
    # Do something
    plt.legend([X.name,Y.name])
```

but I found boring to to instantiate a class with `A = MyClass('nameA'), B = MyClass('nameB')`. I wish to instantiate my classes with `A = MyClass(), B = MyClass()` and retrieve the instances names for the plot inside the `my_plot` function.

Comment: You should read e.g. https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html - names are _labels_, the identifiers (whether none, one or many) to which they're assigned are not properties of the instances. Maybe use a _dictionary_, then you can use the key (name) and the value (instance)?

Comment: `d = {'A': MyClass(), 'B': MyClass()}`. Now `d['A']` and `d['B']` are your references, not `A` and `B`. More importantly, the names are now *data*, not code, and can be passed into `my_plot`.